# Get class name from constructor?

Tags: c#

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyObject object = new MyObject();
        }
    }
    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetCallerClass());  // Out: 'Program'
        }
    }
```

Can I get class name, which called th constructor (like in my code)?
I think System.Reflection can help me, but which is method I should use?

Comment: Does it have to be the class name or would the file and line number be OK too?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, No, it should be class name(or typeof(class)) only.